# How to sort out code problem throwing error of converting parameter at index 0;

Tags: java, testing, gradle, collections, set

While testing my code with @ParameterizedTest as below:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;

import java.util.Set;

public class GamblingMachineTestSuite {

    private GamblingMachine gamblingMachine = new GamblingMachine();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/GamblingMachineTestData.csv", numLinesToSkip = 11)

    public void shouldGetCorrectNumbers ( Set<Integer> input) throws InvalidNumbersException {
        gamblingMachine.howManyWins((input));
    }
```

I get feedback with the  :

> Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type >java.lang.String to type java.util.Set

Could anybody help me to sort it out... if possible? 
I suppose  it may have something to do with the gradle builder. I use IDE = InteliJ 2020.1  at Ubuntu 19.04; gradle = 6.2.2 version;
Thank you in advance; 
StBanas;

Comment: Please review the usage of CsvFileSource, it will give you a parameter for each column provided as far as i remember. Not a Set of Integers. See for example this article: https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5

Comment: Many thanks Tom; I will follow that;